# IE issues with HTML5 headers.char utf-8 encode is shown as error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, char, encode

I am trying to make my site working on IE 9. But from the beginning itself, it shows many errors.

```
HTML1114: Codepage iso-8859-1 from (HTTP header) overrides conflicting codepage utf-8 from (META tag) index.html
```

This is the error when I load in IE 9, but it's working fine in Firefox and Chrome. I am using HTML 5, so my header looks like below -

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='0' >  
<meta http-equiv='ETag' content='o2389r-98ur0-w3894tu-q894' />  
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache' />  
<meta name="expires" content="never">
```

Due to these errors, I am stuck. And no jQuery or javascript works. Can't even log in. Please help me. And also, suggest me a debugger for tracking javascript.

Answer (score 3):

This error shows up because you specified encoding inboth **Content-Type HTTP Header** and **`<meta>` tag**, and they specifies different codepage.

It's not an error, it's just a warning and I think it would not break your webpage. Mozilla just doesn't report such warnings but has the same behavior as IE9.

Try to modify your **Content-Type HTTP Header** to give a UTF-8 encoding would probably solve this problem.

Comment: hi,its not showing the  Codepage iso-8859-1  error,but still my $.ajax not working..

Answer (score 0):

I believe your server might be overriding your meta tags. This post might be helpful:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/is/web/thread/2b7be95a-a90b-425f-b799-1b68a6d94f77

For javascript debugging if it's not a complex thing I use the command console.log...

Comment: Thank you..  HTML1114: Codepage iso-8859-1 from (HTTP header) overrides conflicting codepage utf-8 from (META tag) index.html   .This error is not found now.But $.ajax not is still  not working.