# Microsoft Edge shows Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, x-ua-compatible

My project Intranet website is not showing some pages in Microsoft Edge and it is working in IE7 fine and when I tested In the using F12 console it shows below error in console

> Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable form "".
>
> HTML1114: Codepage iso-8859-1 from (HTTP header) overrides conflicting codepage utf-8 from (META tag)

In my Pages it is using as below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

What to change in the DOCTYPE and in the meta tag?

Answer (score 1):

This error shows up because you specified encoding inboth Content-Type HTTP Header and  tag, and they are using different encode methods.

The solution is to modify the Content-Type HTTP Header to give a UTF-8 encoding, or to change the page charset in the meta tag to iso-8859-1 (which may introduce other problems).

More detail, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640175/ie-issues-with-html5-headers-char-utf-8-encode-is-shown-as-error) and the [HTML  charset Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp).